# Rss in a WebView - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rss, webview

So I was doing a WebView for iOS on Xcode, everything is superfine but when i try to open an RSS url with the code below it doesn't work

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"feed://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/9602059";
```

But when I try to open a normal webpage, it runs perfect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using http instead.  I'm not sure that UIWebView understands/handles "feed"

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/9602059";
```

Comment: as @max suggested, you probably aren't going to get an out-of-the-box RSS reader using UIWebView.  You'll have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do that for weeks but couldn't succeed. It all seems so complicated and I can't add an existing rss to my project. This is cracking my nerves, every time I try to make it somethings went wrong and this web view parsing looked like my last resort.

Comment: It's no a particularly complicated process, but I must admit that it's a pain to deal with as a beginner. Always post questions on here if you get stuck / find something complicated. There is always someone willing to help.

Comment: lots of examples and tutorials for an iOS RSS reader - try [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) for starters

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL for more info, provided you are subscribed to the iOS Developer Programme.

If not, here is a quote:

> The "hungrysoft.com"-link posted above did not work for me either. 
>   Specifically, I got back an XML file and when the UIWebView attempted
>   to render that file it appeared without any formatting, even though
>   the XML-file contained references to style sheets.   My guess is that
>   somehow Safari knows how to render XML files with references to style
>   sheets, but that UIWebView does not.

Furthermore, I don't believe that UIWebViews support the feed:// protocol. Try using the NSXMLParser to parse the information instead.

Comment: Thank you max_ webview don't open feed:// but safari somehow does that. Anyhow I'm searching for an rss training but all I did found was very old articles that are not working correctly as I wanted.